# Native hints/tooltips under Vista/7 with Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, tooltip, delphi-7

I am trying to reproduce native hints/tooltips under Windows Vista/7 using Delphi7.

I've found [a nice component](http://stanleyxu2005.blogspot.com/2008/01/native-hint-window-class.html) which could solve the issue, but it only partially works. TListView components' tooltips aren't shown. The screen is blinking for a sec but no tooltips are shown.

How can I display native tooltips in Windows with Delphi 7?

Comment: I cannnot reproduce this with in D7 on W7. Setting Hint property of a ListView shows a native hint. And in ViewStyle=vsReport it shows a native hint for truncated values, even if not using this unit. Is there a special kind of situation you are talking about?

Comment: Are you it's a native hint? The native hint has a bluish gradient backgruond

Answer (score 1):

With latest Delphi versions, if the option "Enable runtime themes" is checked, the tooltips are like you want them. (If it's unchecked, the background is yellow).
I just test it with Delphi XE and TListView (vsIcon & vsReport).

So one easy (but not free) solution is to migrate to a recent Delphi version.